# Finding the date of the oldest and newest entity with a certain attribute in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

Let's say a have a Datomic schema like this:

```
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident              :app/createdAt
  :db/doc                "The date and time when the entity was created (not necessarily the same as tx time)"
  :db/valueType          :db.type/instant
  :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
  {:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident              :app/type
  :db/doc                "The type of the entity"
  :db/valueType          :db.type/string
  :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

And multiple of such entities are created in the lifetime of the application. I'm interested in finding the `:app/createdAt` instant/date for the oldest and newest entity of a certain type (`:app/type`), say "type1". How would such a query look like in Datomic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to use a Datalog query:

```
[:find (min ?c) (max ?c) :in $ ?type :where
 [?e :app/type ?type]
 [?e :app/createdAt ?c]]
```

### Performance considerations

As of Datomic 0.9.5385, the Datalog engine will perform a full scan of the entities matching the `[?e :app/type ?type]` clause; if there are many such entities, this can result in many network roundtrips to storage, high resource consumption on the Peer, and significant latency.

Fortunately, you can use Datomic's [Optimization of Range Predicates](http://blog.datomic.com/2015/01/datalog-enhancements.html) to restrict the number of datoms scanned by the query. For instance, to compute the maximum creation date, if you know that at least one such entity was created after August 2016, you can call:

```
(d/q '[:find (max ?c) . :in $ ?type ?lower-bound :where
       [?e :app/createdAt ?c]
       [(>= ?c ?lower-bound)]
       [?e :app/type ?type]]
  db #inst "2016-08")
```

Note that the order of Datalog clauses matters.

Disclaimer: I am not knowledgeable about the source code of Datomic, and am only inferring the above assertions from personal experiments.

Comment: Do you know anything of the performance of such a query? What if you have several thousands of these entities? Mainly concerned about the performance of "max"?